# sfGuard custom algorithm_callable

Tags: php, symfony1, sfguard

I am trying to make custom algorithm for password hashing. I try to do this.

In app.cfg:

```
sf_guard_plugin:
  algorithm_callable: [Hlp, noHash]
```

In apps/frontend/lib/Hlp.php:

```
class Hlp
{
  function noHash($password) //tried to make public or public static, but it didn't work either
  {
    return $password;
  }
}
```

And in my database 'algorithm' is set to 'noHash'.
When I try to log in I get following error:

> The algorithm callable "noHash" is not callable.

I am using php 5.2.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
Change in app.yml: algorithm_callable: 'Hlp::noHash'

Changed algorith in db to 'Hlp::noHash'

Marking hakre's answer as correct for providing useful tip.

Comment: Is your class file being loaded? If not, the function is not callable. Check the error log.

Comment: hakre, I have other functions in this class and they work fine in other parts of my webpage. I don't see any mentions of Hlp class in log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **sfGuardPlugin 1.3** expects the function to be static in case you want to call a class member.

However in your case the error message explicitly states that you're calling a global public function, otherwise the error message would have been

> The algorithm callable "Hlp::noHash" is not callable.

So check the settings. Check the PHP requirements. And if in doubt, [read the source](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfGuardPlugin/branches/1.3/lib/model/plugin/PluginsfGuardUser.php).

Answer (score 0):

You should properly define your functions. Time to leave the PHP 4 era behind. Also, you need PHP >5.2.4

```
...
public static function noHash($password)
...
```

And you do mean app.yml right?