# How to hash a file using an algorithm I created

Tags: php, hash, cryptography

I'm trying to hash a file (called hash.txt) using an algorithm (MD9) I've just created.

Here is the code

```
<?php


        function MD9($m)
        {
            static $s = array(
                 41,  46,  67, 201, 162, 216, 124,   1,  61,  54,  84, 161, 236, 240, 6,
                 19,  98, 167,   5, 243, 192, 199, 115, 140, 152, 147,  43, 217, 188,
                 76, 130, 202,  30, 155,  87,  60, 253, 212, 224,  22, 103,  66, 111, 24,
                138,  23, 229,  18, 190,  78, 196, 214, 218, 158, 222,  73, 160, 251,
                245, 142, 187,  47, 238, 122, 169, 104, 121, 145,  21, 178,   7,  63,
                148, 194,  16, 137,  11,  34,  95,  33, 128, 127,  93, 154,  90, 144, 50,
                 39,  53,  62, 204, 231, 191, 247, 151,   3, 255,  25,  48, 179,  72, 165,
                181, 209, 215,  94, 146,  42, 172,  86, 170, 198,  79, 184,  56, 210,
                150, 164, 125, 182, 118, 252, 107, 226, 156, 116,   4, 241,  69, 157,
                112,  89, 100, 113, 135,  32, 134,  91, 207, 101, 230,  45, 168,   2, 27,
                 96,  37, 173, 174, 176, 185, 246,  28,  70,  97, 105,  52,  64, 126, 15,
                 85,  71, 163,  35, 221,  81, 175,  58, 195,  92, 249, 206, 186, 197,
                234,  38,  44,  83,  13, 110, 133,  40, 132,   9, 211, 223, 205, 244, 65,
                129,  77,  82, 106, 220,  55, 200, 108, 193, 171, 250,  36, 225, 123,
                  8,  12, 189, 177,  74, 120, 136, 149, 139, 227,  99, 232, 109, 233,
                203, 213, 254,  59,   0,  29,  57, 242, 239, 183,  14, 102,  88, 208, 228,
                166, 119, 114, 248, 235, 117,  75,  10,  49,  68,  80, 180, 143, 237,
                 31,  26, 219, 153, 141,  51, 159,  17, 131, 20
            );

            // Step 1. Append Padding Bytes
            $pad = 16 - (strlen($m) & 0xF);
            $m.= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

            $length = strlen($m);

            // Step 2. Append Checksum
            $c = str_repeat(chr(0), 16);
            $l = chr(0);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i+= 16) {
                for ($j = 0; $j < 16; $j++) {
                    // RFC1319 incorrectly states that C[j] should be set to S[c xor L]
                    //$c[$j] = chr($s[ord($m[$i + $j] ^ $l)]);
                    // per <http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=1319>, however, C[j] should be set to S[c xor L] xor C[j]
                $c[$j] = chr($s[ord($m[$i + $j] ^ $l)] ^ ord($c[$j]));
                $l = $c[$j];
            }
        }
        $m.= $c;

        $length+= 16;

        // Step 3. Initialize MD Buffer
        $x = str_repeat(chr(0), 48);

        // Step 4. Process Message in 16-Byte Blocks
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i+= 16) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < 16; $j++) {
                $x[$j + 16] = $m[$i + $j];
                $x[$j + 32] = $x[$j + 16] ^ $x[$j];
            }
            $t = chr(0);
            for ($j = 0; $j < 18; $j++) {
                for ($k = 0; $k < 48; $k++) {
                    $x[$k] = $t = $x[$k] ^ chr($s[ord($t)]);
                    //$t = $x[$k] = $x[$k] ^ chr($s[ord($t)]);
                }
                $t = chr(ord($t) + $j);
            }
        }

        // Step 5. Output
        return bin2hex(substr($x, 0, 16));
    }

    ?>
```

When I try to run

```
<?php

include 'md9.php';

class hashing {
     public static function filehash($file,$hash) {
     if (file_exists($file)) {
         return hash($hash,file_get_contents($file));
     }
     else {
         return "Error Occurred: File Does Not Exist";
     }
 }
 }

  echo hashing::filehash("hash.txt","md9")."<br />";

?>
```

am getting an error "Warning: hash() [function.hash]: Unknown hashing algorithm: md9"

I have tried hashing a string of characters using the same algorithm and it's working well.

I don't know what's the problem with the algorithm and hashing files.

Somebody sort me out please

Comment: the hash() library set doesn't allow "external" hashes. it has a list of build-in ones you can use, and your md9 isn't part of it. exactly why are you building your own hash? hash algorithms are not something you just yank off the back of a cereal box.

Comment: I think [PHP hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) not accept user defined hash algorithm...

Comment: hash doesn't recognize you 'md9' algo .. you could read the file into a string and use your algorithm ..

Comment: Thanks @MarcB . :). I'm doing a project where am supposed to build my own algorithm so that I can hash a file and also a string of characters. Then how do I go about creating my own hash() function that will implement the same effect as the in-built hash() function?

Comment: @GeoPhoenix Am suppose to hash the file itself, not the contents.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the documentation, here's the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php), you'll see that you can't just plug in any algorithm you decide. "md9" does not mean anything to PHP. It is something you've made up. You need to implement the method yourself, to hash the file, and call that method from filehash. Although, a word of advice. Making up your own hashing algorithms isn't the safest method. The established hashing algorithms (sha1, sha-2) are provably secure.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisCooney, but  how do I go about creating my own filehash() function that will implement the same effect as the in-built hash() function?

Comment: Is this for a school / university project, or for your own personal coding? If it's for your own personal coding, it's really not a good idea to do this. If it's for a school project, they really aren't teaching you best practise. All the same [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382579/sfguard-custom-algorithm-callable) is similar to your's, and should put you in the right (allbeit insecure) direction.

Comment: It's a school project, I even told the lecturer that I highly doubt that this won't work out. Thanks a lot